# Distribution Lists in Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have a (standard edition) Google Apps domain, and I'm looking for the best way to add a few standard email addresses (admin@, webmaster@, etc.) without using the catch-all approach (I want to catch a few specific addresses, not the entire spam-world).

From what I have seen, I have a few options.

- I could create accounts for each, optionally forwarding to my main inbox. (Not ideal
- I could create groups for each, adding my main account to each group.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

(Possibly related to [Creating Aliases in Google Apps Email for Non-Users](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/creating-aliases-in-google-apps-email-for-non-users) except the accepted answer doesn't fit my situation, and the question was for multiple domains.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We needed to setup a distribution list where there were many aliases but they all were delivered to the same users. The best approach we found was creating a fake user account, setting up aliases on that account, forwarding the email to a real group, and using the group membership function to setup the distribution list. Works reasonably well, but having aliases for a group would be better.

Looks like you can also [nest groups within groups](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33343&topic=14869). There is at least one [help topic](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=7bc12955ff42a515&hl=en) that recommends this approach. The above mentioned approach does give a few other features however, such as vacation responders and the ability to backup mailing list email using POP/IMAP.

Comment: Forwarding filters are limited to 20 per account, so while this idea has merit, it is slightly limited in that respect. However, for my purposes it will work fine. Thanks!

Comment: If you need more than 20 then simply create a group with all of the members and forward to the group instead of directly to each account.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the possibilities you listed, you can also create mail aliases to your main account (if you're the only one who should get the mail otherwise I'd create groups).

`Users and Groups` > Your Main Address > `Add nickname` > Type it in > `Save changes`

Comment: I like this idea (and didn't know about it), but I may in the future need it to be moved to another account (or indeed, multiple accounts).

Comment: @Raithlin: I'd suggest you create the nicknames for your main accounts now and if you need it at another account just remove them on one and add it on another account. If you need multiple accounts  you can either just forward them from your main account or remove the aliases from it and create a group.

Comment: Thanks, Neo. It's worked out simpler to go ahead and create the groups anyway. It just seemed weird to have to create groups to do this - I think it may have to do with Google's naming the lists "groups".

Answer (score 0):

Your title says you want DLs, but your question says you want specific email addresses.  So I'm confused.   But to create specific addresses quickly:

- Sign in as domain administrator
- Advanced tools > Bulk upload
- Prepare a CSV file in the format specified
  (one row per acct, header row, c1=username, c2=firstname,c3=lastname, c4=password
- Upload the file.

Comment: I was wanting specific email addresses that would be forwarded to main accounts - so DLs with specific email addresses. ;)